# A class property gets cleared at the end of a method execution

Tags: php, oop

I have a structure like this:

```
class My_Class extends Another_Class {
  private $my_data = array();

  public function append_to_my_data() {
    $my_data[] = $this->get_result();
  }
}
```

The append_to_my_data method is called from an AJAX recursion, it is supposed to handle an array by small pieces and combine results by appending them to the $my_data property. But it seems that on each call of this method, the $my_data property is empty again and does not contain the results from the previous call.

Why does it happen? Should I look for another method of storing this data? I would not like to store the data in my JavaScript recursion because it might be quite deep and the data might get quite large.

Comment: PHP is stateless by default, If you want to save data between requests you'll have to use database or sessions.

Comment: **1.** Class properties are accessed using  `$this`, example: `$this->my_data[] = $this->get_result();`. Without it, it' just a local variable inside that specific method and will be reset on each method call.  **2.** Every request to your PHP-script with Ajax will be a totally new request. No data that was set in previous requests are kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By AJAX, I assume you mean Javascript.
This tells me one thing, you try to persist data between http requests from your client app (the Javascript code) and your server app code (PHP).
Be aware the JS/client runs on the user's machine in the browser, and the PHP code runs on your own server machine. Two totaly different machines with separate memory/hard disk and CPU.
To persist data on the server between different http requests there are many ways/approaches you can use.
The two MOST common ways are to use [php sessions](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20sessions%20tutorials&oq=php%20sessions%20tutorials&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4556j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and/or MySQL database, there are many more ways to do it, the two above are the most common ones.

And, to access an object property, you will need to use the `$this` 
i.e.:

```
$this->my_data[] = $this->get_result();
and not
$my_data[] = $this->get_result();
```